# Check and fix topology of polygons within one shapefile

Tags: r, gis

I am currently working with one vector file (one shapefile) that contains different topology errors, ie. overlaps of polygons, polygons within polygons and duplicates of polygons. The shapefile is a publicly available dataset that contains the agricultural application for the Common Agricultural Policy Payments within the EU. Hence, I assume this topology errors occur "naturally"/on the way because farmers and other stakeholders are asked to create vector files of their area for which they apply for funding.

I understand how to identify/check and fix the different topology errors in QGIS (see "Topology Checker Panel" and "Check Geometries" Plugin), however I would prefer to process this in R due to transparency and reproducibility reason. I expect the sf package with its st_overlaps function to be helpful, but neither do I understand how to process the results from st_overlaps further nor do I understand if there is a way to set my own rules regarding the fixing of the different errors (e.g. polygon within another polygon -> delete the smaller one, i.e. the one which is within the polygon or overlaps of two polygons -> divide the overlapping area of two polygons by two).

It would be great to receive some ideas!

```
library(sf)
agri_overlaps <- st_overlaps(agri_shp)
```

Comment: Why not use the [Processing Modeler](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_graphical_modeler.html) that comes with QGIS? Likely to be easier to implement and it meets your reproducibility needs.